# Allowing users to update SQL Extended Properties via SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-interface

I would like to be able to grant non-admin users the ability to add/update SQL extended properties for objects in a DB via SSMS.
I've looked all over for simple solutions (though I'm open to suggestions), and for ease of use reasons, SSMS would be by far the best for us (the users in question already use it, it's the only simple way to see and update existing extended properties, it would require little/no code...).
I read that users are supposed to need ALTER or CONTROL in order to change them, but I'm hoping to get around that, and obviously can't give this much permission to regular users.

Looking at the script SSMS uses to update these, it's simply:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_updateextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'This is test  
description 1.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', 
@level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Table_1'
```

I understand you can grant access to stored procedures that do things users wouldn't normally have rights to do.  I was able to use:

```
grant exec on sys.sp_addextendedproperty to [AD\testuser]
grant exec on sys.sp_updateextendedproperty to [AD\testuser]
grant exec on sys.sp_dropextendedproperty to [AD\testuser]
```

while in the master DB context to grant this permission.  However, I still get:
"Msg 1088, Level 16, State 30, Procedure sp_updateextendedproperty, Line 36
Cannot find the object "dbo.Table_1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions." when I try to alter extended properties as this testuser via SSMS.  Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: Not sure whether it will work, but try granting reference permissions to "Table_1" to [AD\testuser] as well.

Comment: Well, you could put the call to extended property procedures inside a wrapper procedure, have that execute as owner (or sign it with a cert), and give the user execute rights on that procedure. Of course this means they'll have to call your stored procedure, unless you plan to de-compile SSMS and make it point to yours instead.

Comment: I tried granting "References" permission for the user on both the table and the DB, and it had no effect.

The code that SSMS gives me for sp_updateextendedproperty if I click Modify might be what "Line 36" is referring to.  It's the return after the sp uses sys.sp_validname on the object passed to it.  I tried running the same "grant" statement on sys.sp_validname, no effect so far.  Maybe THAT sp points to something that has to be granted permission to?  Or am I on the wrong track in that the grant on sp_updateextendedproperty itself should have handled everything downstream?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I'm creating a web based app to do this for our data warehouse team. I have a SQL user account to access a database from a selection.  The minimum permissions I've seen so far are **Alter Schema** and **View Definitions**.  This is set for a single user, which is added to each Database that is available to the app. The procedures that MSSMS uses to view and edit the extended properties are being used in procedures I created so I can use different property values, depending on if they are working on Schema, Table or Column values. The User has Execute permission on those. They all reside in a central database, which controls the web app.

It works fine, even with linked servers, but not sure that there is something a little tighter.

Comment: I intended to create the same sort of web app.